# Using round function in QGIS expression?

Tags: qgis-3, expression, round-function

I created a grid of rectangular polygons with the `Create Grid` function, from the *Vector Creation* group of the *Processing Toolbox* in QGIS 3.4.2.
The rectangles measure half a degree of longitude by half a degree of latitude.

When I want to label the polygons, I write an expression that rounds the values of latitude and longitude attributes to 2 decimal places, since the attributes created in the grid brings many decimal places.

**But the `round` function rounds the values badly.**

I know that I can create new attributes that express the coordinates with fewer decimal places and label the entities based on those attributes, but I was struck by the behavior of the function. I expected it to round to the nearest value.

**Does anyone know what the problem is that the `round` function wrongly rounds off the decimal number?**

Attached screenshots of *Source Fields* and the Attribute Table.

[image: source-fields]

[image: round-expression]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I cannot replicate the same behavior that you have. I created a grid with 0.5 degree width of latitude and longitude, and I round it to 2 decimal degree and it works fine. Then I added another column with a value of 50.49 and round it to 1 decimal and it worked as expected and I got 50.5. Here is the table with values:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not sure what was going wrong in your case. I used the exact version of QGIS 3.4.2.

**Update**

You are right. If I use negative latitude and longitude, I got strange results. I think this is a bug in QGIS 3.4.2. You should report this as a bug in QGIS 3.4.2 to the QGIS developer team [here](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html):

[image]

**Update 2**

The issue of rounding negative values was fixed in the latest stable release of QGIS 3.4.4-3. Now rounding negative numbers produces correct results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I am creating a new grid in a new project to find the solution, but the problem persists. However, I am realizing that the problem does not arise if I create the grid in positive latitude and longitude coordinates. Could you try it in negative coordinates (South and West)?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca You are right, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @ahmadhanb, I just opened [this bug report](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20861).

Comment: This issue was already fixed in the latest stable version 3.4.4-3, if you want to update your answer I can accept it.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Thank you for updating me about the issue.