# QGIS labels rounding error

Tags: qgis, labeling, spatialite

I wish to use rounded values as labels using QGIS 3.4.4. My field is type "double" and the the data source is a Spatialite table. I notice two odd behaviors linked to this problem. First, the attribute values have false precision. For example, in the source file, a value is 16.300000, but it appears as 16.300000000000001 in QGIS. Second, when I attempt to use the round function under labels, the value can either be truncated to zero decimal places using `round` or the precision can't be reduced at all, no matter what precision I supply to `round.` How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Which QGIS 3 version are you using? Could you please specify the exact version number from `Help → About QGIS`?

Comment: QGIS version 3.4.4

Comment: I remember there was a bug in QGIS 3.4.2 regarding rounding negative number and it was solved with QGIS 3.4.4-3, as you can see in the answer to the question: [Using round function in QGIS expression?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/306761/63384). Maybe your case was reported also as a bug, I am not sure. To make everything clear, try to update to the latest LTR 3.10.8, and see if update solve the problem.

Comment: The first issue is not an issue. You can test with https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/ that it is not possible to save decimal value 16.3 accurately into double. When converted back it becomes `16.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125`.